# Importing Python module prints docstring of different, unrelated script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I've encountered this issue with two separate modules now, one that I attempted to download myself *(**Quartz**; could probably be the way I installed it, but let's ignore this scenario for now)* and another that I installed using `pip install` *(**Pandas**; let's focus on this one)*.

I wrote a two-line script that includes just `import pandas` and `print('test')`, for testing purposes. When I execute this in the terminal, instead of printing `test` to confirm the script runs correctly, it prints the docstring for another completely unrelated script:

```
[hidden]~/Python/$ python3 test.py
Usage: python emailResponse.py [situation] - copy situation response
```

The second line is a docstring I wrote for a simple fetch script for responding to emails, which is unrelated. What's worse is, if I just envoke `Python3` in the terminal, and try `import pandas`, it'll print that same docstring and take me out of Python3 and back into the terminal shell / bash *(sorry if this is not the right verbiage; still learning)*. The same results happen trying `import Quartz` as well, but no other modules are impacted (at least, that I'm aware of).

I'm at a complete loss why this might be the case. It was easy enough to avoid using `Quartz`, but I need `Pandas` for work purposes and this issue is starting to directly affect my work.

Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Did you create a file called `pandas.py` of your own somewhere?

Comment: @BrenBarn Just looked through my entire comp; no, the only `pandas.py` files I see are the ones for the module itself. I've had a few internal work folks tell me that a clean re-install of Python3 might be necessary... but they weren't 100% sure, they just couldn't understand why my situation was happening at all.

Comment: The problem is almost surely due to a file you've created that is shadowing some library.  It may not be pandas but some other library imported indirectly by pandas.  Do you know what that `emailResponse.py` file is?  Is it a file you created?  If so, can you perhaps edit it and insert a `raise ValueError("Oh no!")` or something at the top to generate a stack trace and perhaps gain more info?

Comment: @BrenBarn strangely, I don't even have an `emailResponse.py` anymore. I changed the name of that file to just `email.py` and the docstring for it was modified too, to `# emailResponse.py - Easy way to copy/paste responses to work emails.` This is all being run on my local machine, btw - so no wacky server syncing stuff going on (I think?).

Comment: @BrenBarn Edited as best as I can because I can't figure out how to paste the script nicely in a comment, but actually I do see where it's being printed. In that same file, the script opens with:

`import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
 print('Usage: python emailResponse.py [situation] - copy situation response')
 sys.exit()`

But why would that be affecting other scripts, or even simply just importing modules?

Comment: There is a builtin Python library called `email`.  Probably something else you are importing is doing `import email`.  This runs your script, and your script does `sys.exit()`, so it just quits instantly.  Try renaming your script to something that doesn't shadow a builtin library.

Comment: @BrenBarn ah i had no idea... that totally did the trick, thanks man! seems like such a silly issue now, in hindsight, but it derailed me for a few weeks!